# Preventing Apache from logging HAProxy requests

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy

I have two [HAProxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAProxy) VMs and two Apache VMs (vagrant machines) as follows.

```
192.168.50.11 HAPROXY VM1
192.168.50.12 HAPROXY VM2
192.168.50.21 APACHE VM1
192.168.50.22 APACHE VM2
```

The problem I'm having is the Apache `access.log` file is growing every second, because both HAProxy servers are pinging both Apache servers even when there is no request from any client. I need to stop recording unnecessary logs like shown below. I have the keepalived service running on both HAProxy servers.

```
$sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log

192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:49 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:51 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.12 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:51 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:51 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:53 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.12 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:53 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:53 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:55 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.12 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:55 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
192.168.50.11 - - [09/Jul/2016:12:46:55 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 180 "-" "-"
.......
.......
```

These are not actual requests from anyone.

**haproxy.cfg**

```
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    maxconn 2000
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 50000
    timeout server 50000

frontend http-in
    bind 192.168.50.10:80
    default_backend webservers

backend webservers
    balance roundrobin
    stats enable
    stats auth admin:admin
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server webserver1 192.168.50.21:80 check
    server webserver2 192.168.50.22:80 check
```

Comment: Read the section about "conditional logging" in the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to set an [environment flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html) for certain requests with the [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) directive and then instruct Apache to not log requests matching that:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.gif do-not-log-this-request
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "192\.168\.50\.11" do-not-log-this-request
SetEnvIf Request_Method OPTIONS do-not-log-this-request

CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!do-not-log-this-request
```

Comment: I changed default one `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined` to `LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined` to get actual IP of client instead of HAProxy's IP in access logs. Your `SetEnvIf Request_Method OPTIONS do-not-log-this-request` solves it anyway.